# tf.keras.binary_crossentropy gives worse result than calling 'binary_crossentropy'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, loss-function

**QUESTION 1:** Why does calling binary_crossentropy by its name with a string 'binary_crossentropy' gives different (better) results than calling, the same(?), tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy function inside a custom loss function?

**QUESTION 2:** What am I doing wrong?

**PROBLEM:**
I'm trying to solve a mystery of different results I get when I use:

```py
def bc_custom(y_true, y_pred): return tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
model1.compile(optimizer=tf.compat.v2.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE, loss = bc_custom, metrics=['binary_accuracy'])
```

and

```py
model2.compile(optimizer=tf.compat.v2.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE, loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics=['binary_accuracy'])
```

Basically:

- the difference is in calling binary_crossentropy inside a custom function (model1) and the same function by its name with a string (model2),
- following https://stackoverflow.com/a/57331394/5536388 advice, I set metrics to binary_accuracy,
- both models use the same dataset which may only differ after being shuffled in the training process,
- the models solve a multilabel classification problem. The final layer uses the sigmoid activation function.

**RESULTS:**
I made several tests and each time model1:

- is being taught much slower:

epoch, accuracy, loss, accuracy_val, loss_val

```
0,0.01571397,0.08330947177696847,0.08565965,0.06395021689980937
1,0.14730678,0.04977951637815227,0.24956022,0.039584608338986936 
2,0.2366954,0.98736,0.2366954,0.03144164173531004,0.27801147,0.99116695,0.27801147,0.022898457557974424
```

vs model2

```
0,0.98126763,0.08199372373072011,0.9798808,0.061917345579108135
1,0.98271894,0.0477434622772295,0.98628557,0.03482157470263099
2,0.9884866,0.9884866,0.24891642,0.028994456771504733,0.9914624,0.9914624,0.27778202,0.022188534344907987
```

- model1 gives worse results, at least in the beginning (haven't waited till the final results):
  [image: model1 results after epoch 0]
  results of model1 after epoch 0
  [image: model2 results after epoch 0]
  results of model2 after epoch 0

The expected results are 1 point-wide straight-to-top lines in many positions (10, 30, 50, 110, 140, 210, 230) as the model2 is clearly going to and, in the end, reaches the correct answer in 98% of cases.

Comment: Can you try tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy() so without y_true and y_pred and give it directly into it, so loss =  tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy()

Comment: I'll try the first idea. Regarding the second idea, I won't because the function that is provided to the loss param is a customizable param inside a certain dictionary in my app so I can switch a loss function from one to another by changing its value. Just for the sake of the question I made a simpler version of the code.

Comment: Checked. The execution fails. I think it has to do with tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy the requirement of y_true, y_pred params. Although, I also have an error of OOM which does not happen when I provide the params in the first place.

Comment: That's a typo: you are setting `loss` to `'binary_accuracy'` in the second case!

Comment: You're right; made a mistake writing the post. I corrected that. Thanks.